# Build Microsoft Teams Message Extension for Action Command

Tags: microsoft-teams, add-in, teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js

I want to build a Microsoft Teams message extension. I have read all the documents but they are all related to command box, message box and creating cards.

Can anyone tell me how it works?

I have created a message extension "Hello World" using Teams Toolkit. I followed this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/build-message-extension?tabs=teamstoolkitcodespaces.

I created a message extension but it appears in the message box.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the option in More Action, you have to add the commands in composeExtensions section of your app manifest schema.

[image]

Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#composeextensions

Please refer below document and sample for detailed description:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/action-commands/define-action-command
2. https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/msgext-action/csharp

Comment: With this sample message extension, when the action is selected on the message on a specific channel from More option context menu, Sample composes a message, user can send the message. I would like to perform some operation based off of the message, such as create a task based on the message. Is it possible to forward this message to the bot for starting the some dialog flow?

Comment: @Snekithan - After sending the message from the compose area, would you like to perform any specific activity on the message?

Comment: In my scenario, user selects a message (by more action and select the message extension context menu command, which allows performing some action based off the message, so I am able to implement to provide task dialog and user can configure and submit the action.